# JSF How do I get the previously selected value of MultiselectListbox?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've got a `multiselectListbox` and want the previously selected Value. 
For example:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/multiSelectListbox.xhtml

and i want the selected Item from `<Group 1>`

Is there a option in JSF to set a Variable? Or maybe with JavaScript?

Comment: Why not saving it ?!?

Comment: Your change in the question makes it unclear. The upvoted answer is **the** answer to the original question. Now by changing it you just ask for _**the** selected item from "Group 1"_ Unclear for me

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is an option in JSF but as selection is JSF is nothing but calling the setter method of that particular field in Backingbean

in the following code snippet

```
<p:multiSelectListbox value="#{multiSelectView.selection}" effect="slide" header="Categories" showHeaders="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{multiSelectView.categories}" />
</p:multiSelectListbox>
```

here

`value=#{multiSelectView.selection}`  will call the setter method for selection in multiSelectView bean. 
So modifying setter method to copy the value to another variable before setting the current value can help in coping the value to another variable before setting it to a new variable

```
 public class MultiSelectView {

private List<SelectItem> categories;    
private String selection;
private String previousSelection;

...
public void setSelection(String newSelection) {
    this.previousSelection=this.selection;
    this.selection = newSelection;
}
```

so now you have both current selection and previous selection. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The selected values can be mapped to a `Collection` in the backing bean. Please refer the following example which shows multiple ways of handling data from a multiSelectListBox https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-multiple-select-listbox-example

Comment: i dont know if i can do this with a <p:multiSelectListBox> from Primefaces... I tried this exampel but it doesnt work. I got all the informations in a List but i need the previously selected Option in a seperate variable..